# Can't Convert list contain multiple class to DataTable

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

i am trying to convert a list to dataTable and then save it to the database , but i am facing a problem . I get an error that column Mapping does not match .

This is my List

```
public static class Program
{
    static Logger _myLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public class Student
    {
        public int int { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblStudentCourses> tblStudentCourses { get; set; }
}

List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
```

This is the extensions that i am using

```
public static DataTable AsDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

    //Get all the properties
    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
        var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
        //Setting column names as Property names
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
    }
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {
            //inserting property values to datatable rows
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
    return dataTable;
}
```

This how i am calling the extension

```
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Student";

                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(student.AsDataTable());
    connection.Close();
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
```

The error :

**The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination**

Comment: Where do you get which exception?

Comment: bulkCopy.WriteToServer(recipientsBulk.AsDataTable());

Comment: This means somewhere in your method `AsDataTable<T>()`. Where in this method? Have a look at the call-stack

Comment: Hi @JohnnyTheCoder, welcome to SO. If you are encountering an error, then you should include the actual error message as well as any exception stack information so we can help you.

Comment: recheck the post please

Comment: @JohnnyTheCoder Are you able to read data in data table?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Use [FastMember's](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) ObjectReader to create an IDataReader on top of any collection, eg :

```
var student = new List<Student>();
...
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(student, "Id", "Name", "Email","PhoneNumber")) 
{ 
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
    bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

SqlBulkCopy can use either a DataTable or IDataReader. `ObjectReader.Create` creates an object that wraps any collection and exposes it through an IDataReader interface that can be used with SqlBulkCopy.

It's also possible to use Linq-to-Dataset's [CopyToDataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTableExtensions_CopyToDataTable__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) or MoreLinq's [ToDataTable](https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_Extensions_ToDataTableExtension_ToDataTable__1.htm) extension methods to create a DataTable from an IEnumerable. These will have to read the entire IEnumerable though and cache all data in the DataTable. This can be expensive if there are a lot of rows.

ObjectReader on the other hand doesn't need to cache anything

Comment: `ObjectReader` is the way to go. But I still think you have to supply the ColumnMappings to SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: cause i got Unexpected existing transaction

Comment: @JohnnyTheCoder you can't, either with a DataTable or data reader. SqlBulkCopy writes to a single table at a time. You'll have to extract the courses to a separate DataTable or collection and insert them. If you load the objects through an ORM it would be better if you *didn'* load related entities this way. ORMs aren't suited to bulk operations

Answer (score 0):

The error `The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination`

happen usually for 3 causes:

- You didn't provide any ColumnMappings, and there is more column in the source than in the destination.
- You provided an invalid column name for the source.
- You provided an invalid column name for the destination.

In your case, you didn't supply column mapping. Here is an online example similar to your scenario: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WaeUi9

To fix it:

- Provide a ColumnMappings

For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zry2tb

More information about this error can be found here: https://sqlbulkcopy-tutorial.net/columnmapping-does-not-match

Answer (score 0):

**If you are able to read data in data table then change your code like below**

```
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Student";
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("<list field name>", "<database field name>");
//Map all your column as above
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

I hope this works for your problem.

Comment: I also want to add data of tblStudentCourses . How that will work with your solution ?

Comment: your error is showing that your fields are not matched.. so you need to mapped them both..List field name and data base field name.